# $\bf{Z}$-module homomorphism and $\bf{Q}$-module homorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

$R$-modules are also $\bf{Z}$-modules and $R$-module homomorphisms are also $\bf{Z}$-module homomorphisms. If $M$ and $N$ are $\bf{Q}$-modules and $f : M \rightarrow N$ is a $\bf{Z}$-module homomorphism, must it also be a $\bf{Q}$-module homomorphism?

Comment: Yes. Can you verify that the definition is satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For any $x/y \in \mathbb{Q}$
$$
    y\cdot f\left(\frac x y m\right) = x\cdot f(m).
$$